# PyMysql failing on insert hitting except block

Tags: python, python-3.x, pymysql

I have code, that attempts to insert each `list-item` from the list `b_result_list`:

```
            db = pymysql.connect(host="localhost",user="root",passwd="password",db="garbagedb" )
            cursor = db.cursor()
            for brl in b_result_list:
                try:
                    sql = """INSERT INTO paths(path) VALUES (brl)"""
                    cursor.execute(sql)
                    db.commit()
                    print("inserted: {}".format(brl))
                except:
                    print("error inserting")
                    db.rollback()
                db.close()
```

I cannot seem to find out why it wont work.

Ive tested the `query manually`, and it works fine.

Does anyone see anything? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I spent some time trying to figure this one out, but finally figured it out.

Here is my working example : I hope that it helps someone someday!

```
    db = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', user='root',passwd='password',db='yourdb')
    cursor = db.cursor()
    for brl in b_result_list:
        try:
            with db.cursor() as cursor:
                sql = "INSERT INTO `paths`(`path`) VALUES (%s)"
                cursor.execute(sql, (brl))
                db.commit()
                print("inserted: {}".format(brl))
        except:
            print("error inserting")
            db.rollback()
    db.close()
```

Further info is here: https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL/blob/master/docs/source/user/examples.rst